# If someone does not downvote defamatory post does that mean they endorse it?

Tags: india, defamation, indian-penal-code

If someone does not downvote defamatory posts on Stackexchange are they liable for defamation under Indian Penal code? I am refering to [section 499](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1041742/) and [section 500](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1408202/).

Comment: I have to point out that your title and the question body ask different things: the title is in error.

Answer (score 10):

**No**

They do not commit the necessary *actus reus* by ignoring, or not even reading, a defamatory post.

To be guilty, one has to act:

> by words either spoken or intended to be read, or by signs or by
> visible representations, makes or publishes any imputation

Answer (score 0):

If I don't read a question, I can't downvote it. You can't claim I endorse a message I haven't even received. In fact, even if received it, to *endorse* a message, I have to take affirmative action that makes my stance clear: No vote is indifference. **Upvoting** would show endorsement. But I still won't **publish** a statement I endorse: only the actual speaker publishes a statement.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted - seems perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: Maybe the person didn't read the post, and was arguing against a claim made.

Answer (score -1):

On the contrary, downvoting tends to be defamatory, but may not be given the [10 statutory exceptions in the law](https://legislative.gov.in/sites/default/files/A1860-45.pdf). Downvoting is a visible representation, which will harm the reputation of a person because the implication
lowers the intellectual character of the person in the eyes of others. Some possibly applicable exceptions are (1) Truth which must be published for the public good, (3)
good faith opinion as to a persons conduct touching a public question, (6) good faith opinion of the merits of any performance submitted to public judgment ("that is a crappy argument"). Spiteful downvoting is defamatory, and can be punished by up to two years in prison. Simultaneously publishing a commend indicating why you think downvoting in a particular instance is required for the public good can help keep you out of prison.